# In LaTeX, when using the memoir class, how do I make References a section instead of the default chapter?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir

Whatever I do, I cannot assign a new name to `\bibsection` when using the memoir class in LaTeX. I want to do that to convince myself that I am actually altering the definition of `\bibsection` because what I really want to do is for my References to be a section and not a chapter.

I've tried using `\usepackage[section]{tocbibind`}, but that just threw an error: "Option clash for package tocbibind". I've also tried various much longer redefinitions of `\bibsection` to no avail.

I feel that I must be overlooking something, so any help will be appreciated.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{FooBar}
%%% From p.306 of 'memman.pdf' (v3.7n) %%%
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}\prebibhook}
\addbibresource{bibsection.bib}

\begin{document}
The more things change, the more they stay the same.\cite{AnacondaInfo2019}
\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would have been happy to, but I didn't see an obvious way of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the bibliography one sectioning level further down with `heading=subbibliography`

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
The more things change, the more they stay the same.\cite{knuth:ct}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy! Thank you. (I wasted the better part of a day trying to get things working.)

Comment: @VladimirG.Ivanovic You're welcome!